# On the proof that $k[\mathbb{A}^2\setminus\{0\}]=k[t_1,t_2]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I don't quite understand a proof that the coordinate ring of the punctured affine plane is $k[\mathbb{A}^2\setminus\{0\}]=k[t_1,t_2]$.

The proof I have takes the principal open sets $D_{\mathbb{A}^2}(T_1)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{A}^2:x\neq 0\}$ and $D_{\mathbb{A}^2}(T_2)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{A}^2:y\neq 0\}$. Here $T_1$ and $T_2$ are the coordinate functions on $\mathbb{A}^2$.

I have the fact that $k[D_X(f)]=k[X]_{(f)}$, so $k[U_1]=k[T_1,T_2,T_1^{-1}]$ and $k[U_2]=k[T_1,T_2,T_2^{-1}]$. Also, 
$k[U_1\cap U_2]=k[D_{\mathbb{A}^2}(T_1T_2)]=k[T_1,T_2,T_1^{-1},T_2^{-1}]$. Then there are the restrictions
$$
k[\mathbb{A}^2]\hookrightarrow k[\mathbb{A}^2\setminus\{0\}]\hookrightarrow k[U_1]\cap k[U_2]\subset k[U_1\cap U_2]=k[T_1,T_2,T_1^{-1},T_2^{-1}].
$$
Since $k[T_1,T_2,T_1^{-1}]\cap k[T_1,T_2,T_2^{-1}]=k[T_1,T_2]$, $k[\mathbb{A}^2\setminus\{0\}]=k[T_1,T_2]$.

What I don't understand is, what is the embedding of $k[\mathbb{A}^2\setminus\{0\}]$ into $k[U_1]\cap k[U_2]$? Wouldn't that give embeddings
$$
k[T_1,T_2]\hookrightarrow k[\mathbb{A}^2\setminus\{0\}]\hookrightarrow k[T_1,T_2]
$$
so why is it even necessary to look at $k[U_1\cap U_2]$ at the end? Thanks.